# Displaying ForeignKey attributes in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I run the api, instead of getting `category` name and `subcategory` name, I get their id,

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "StrawBerry",
        "category": 1,
        "subcategory": 1
    }
]
```

I actually want something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "StrawBerry",
        "category": "Fruits",
        "subcategory": "Berries"
    }
]
```

Note: I already have category and subcategory. I just want to know how to access them.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('parent' , 'category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='subchilren')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('parent' , 'subcategory')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class GetProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'category', 'subcategory')
```

**views.py**

```
class GetProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GetProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to define the `category` and `subcategory` fields of your `GetProductSerializer` as `StringRelatedFields`:

> StringRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its **unicode** method.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield

Or, similarly, as `SlugRelatedFields`:

> SlugRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the relationship using a field on the target.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield

Comment: It's not working, I m not sure why is it so. Could you edit it in my code.
It will be of a great help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more detail about how it isn't working? Are you getting any sort of error?

Comment: I used `category = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)` in `serializers.py` and it gave the this error `TypeError:'Category' object is not iterable` .

Comment: `many=True` should only be used for many-to-any relationships; you should omit it when working with `ForeignKey` relationships as you are here

Comment: Another question, it might be off topic, I did as above, but the fields(category and subcategory) now are not shown, so that I can post.(They were shown if I do not use the above method)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You should be able to create relationships between existing objects using this approach, but you would not be able to create multiple objects at once (i.e., creating a new product, category and subcategory all at the same time through this serializer). For that you would want to use a writable nested serializer: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers. I apologize if I am misunderstanding what you mean

Comment: Thanks! you understood exactly what I meant. I will create as you suggested.